# Запись в определенную строку в файле .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть две строки в file.txt. Мне нужно найти способ записать строку qwertyuiopasdfghjkl, на определенную строку в файле. При этом эта строка должна перезаписывать старую. Читать определенные строки я научился, а вот с записью непонятно.

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines[0]) # Вывод первой строки файла
file.close()
```

Можно записывать через перемещение курсора file.seek(0, 5), но мне это не подходит.
Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Переписать весь файл от начала обновляемой строки до конца файла. Или полностью.

Comment: Ещё одно условие: Нельзя трогать соседние строки.

Comment: Не трогать == не изменять их значение? условие выполняется. Или не трогать == не изменять также их смещение от начала файла? такая задача - нерешаема.

Comment: Ну и не трогайте. Прочитайте и запишите как было

Comment: Если размер строки-замены не совпадает с размером заменяемой строки, то только считать файл целиком и потом записать, подменив искомую строку. По месту никак не получится перезаписать в этом случае.